Vary Capacitance
I'd like to vary two identical capacitors that are connected in parallel and sinusoidally varied with a 180 degree phase shift, i.e. so CT is constant.

The actual value of capacitance isn't too important. Any ideas on a good way to do so? I can't find capacitors that are easy to vary (say based on a signal generator - I only have one, so not sure how I'd do the phase shift).

How do you want to vary them?  What signal is going to be controlling the capacitance?  How much capacitance do you need?  How much variation?  What are these capacitors going to be used for?  This is a very specific problem that sounds like an XY problem.

Sorry, I don't know what XY means (or was it a joke/slander - I'm not sure! - maybe it is good to be ignorant.
I wanted to use a signal generator to vary the capitances. The variation I need is probably quite small - lets say 50uF or 100uF would be reasonable, but needs to be sinusoidal. The variation could be on the order of 20-50 uF.
Specifically, I'm attempting to follow this paper - but it isn't very clear - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304388618302250?casa_token=73lK0l1R-J0AAAAA:vGVIP1W2S-jp3AyAalz0QNqyVH0nGpjywtoJE4bUoK-jpk-Vn0sPgu0lafHhoVLuJgWOxg49Qw

An XY problem regards a proposed solution to an underlying question: https://xyproblem.info/ In other words, for what purpose do you need the capacitor pair? Adjustable capacitors are definitely not that big, hence the question purpose would be valuable to know.

@Tomi 50uF to 100uF is not a small variation in capacitance. Variable capacitors tend to be in the picoFarads. If continuously variable capacitors in the tens of microFarads exists I've never seen any. I would think you'd need to use fixed capacitors and switch more or less of them into the circuit, but that's probably not going to get you the sinusoidal you're looking for.

First option is two varactor diodes after calibration of their circuits should provide this functionality. If rotation of a physical shaft is a requirement then add an encoder to the shaft.
Another option is to calibrate two variable capacitors with an encoder plus stepper motors to perform the required phase shift. Investigate the capacitors used for transmitters such as amateur radio use and not broadcast band variable capacitors.
Look at some relay based, antenna tuner circuits for a switching technique. Use relay switched, fixed capacitors to simulate the required function.
Simplest option is to modify the vanes of two variable capacitors to achieve the required capacitance changes. Investigate the capacitors used for transmitters such as amateur radio use and not broadcast band variable capacitor.

Sorry, that was a typo
